# No ocurre nada cuando doy enviar en formulario php

Tags: php, html5

estoy estudiando php y estoy haciendo un formulario donde sea muy basico que contenga 2 input (Numero 1 y Numero 2) y un boton de enviar, lo que pasa es que al momento de escribir los valores en los input y darle al enviar no ocurre nada, lo unico que hace es refrescar la pagina, aca el codigo

```
<body>
<form action="formularios.php" method="post">
    <label>Numero 1 <input type="text" name="numero1" value="" id="numero1"></label>
    <label>Numero 2<input type="text" name="numero2" value="" id="numero2"></label>
    <button type="submit" id="button" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["button"])){
    $num1=$_POST["numero1"];
    $num2=$_POST["numero2"];

    $suma= $num1+$num2;
    echo "La suma es: " . $suma;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: `POST` funciona con las etiquetas `name` de los elementos, por eso no entra aquí: `if (isset($_POST["button"])){`  Puedes poner esto en el `button`: `<button type="submit" name="button" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>` y funcionará.

Comment: tu código php esta en el mismo formulario intenta quitar formularios.php

Comment: Víctor, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` funciona con las etiquetas `name` de los elementos HTML, por eso no está entrando aquí:

```
if (isset($_POST["button"])){
```

porque en tu HTML no hay ningún elemento cuyo `name` sea  `button`.

Si cambias el botón así:

```
<button type="submit" name="button" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
```

debería funcionar.

---

Extrañamente esto no es mencionado en la explicación de [`$_POST` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php). Aparece apenas [en un comentario de un usuario](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php#119608), hecho hace apenas ¡un año¡.